# How do I change a port restricted IP in a Lightsail instance via API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, aws-cli, amazon-lightsail

I have a port that is IP-restricted in a Lightsail instance. How do I change that restricted IP via API or even aws-cli?

*I prefer via API using cURL.*

Thanks in advance.